Karate testing error with HTTP 307 (redirection)
I am running FastAPI server which exposes an endpoint that can accept PATCH operation to update user profile.
In my feature file, I have defined the scenario like below:
Scenario: PATCH api/v1/profile/ UPDATE
Given path 'api/v1/profile/'
And def jsonBody =
"""
<my JSON payload>
"""
And request data = jsonBody

When method PATCH
Then status 200

Every time when I ran this scenario, Karate in the background generated a request to endpoint 'api/v1/profile' (with no trailing /)
This has caused my FastAPI server to return HTTP 307 (redirection) which attempts to redirect the request to valid endpoint 'api/v1/profile/' (with / trailing)
This issue seems to happen when API request is triggered from Karate feature file, whereas Postman web has no issue at all (When I use postman to fire the PATCH request, I can receive 200 OK)
There was previous blog that proposed a solution to solve this on the server side => https://github.com/fastapi/fastapi/issues/2060
But I wonder if there is a way for me to resolve this issue from Karate side.
Thank you.


This can be actually considered a bug in your server as you seem to have already figured out.
Yes, you can force the trailing slash like this, documented here: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#path
* path 'api/v1/profile', '/'

You can also do it like this if you want:
* path 'api', 'v1', 'profile', '/'

